# Add 2 buttons in android layout-land

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to show two extra textfields when my application is shown in landscape. I know I can do this by copying my original layout to folder layout-land and just add 2 fields, but that way I need to maintain 2 versions of my layout file, the original one and the one copied to folder layout-land. What I actually want is just add two textfields without the need for maintaining 2 copies of a layout file. Can you do that ?

thanks, Steef

Answer (score 2):

The idea which I've thought is may or may not be correct. My idea is to check the device orientation in class file and when the layout is landscape, just manipulate your layout or simply mean just add two text field at that time. Hopefully! it will work.

Happy Coding!!!

Comment: Yes, I though about that to, but I do like the declarative option and prefer to stick to that. I was hoping there was a way using the normal layout in landscape mode, and then adding some elements declarative. That way, I would only have to maintain a single copy of my layout. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

Im beginner but i might have some idea. If you dont want to have 2 layouts file, there is second options-  make styles.xml for portrait and land and you can write style which set visibility. Try something like that.